# python, nfcpy How can i give it a path to an integrated nfc chip on anroid

Tags: python, android, nfc

I want to create a NFC tool for android phone (S20 FE), which can read and emulate cards, but i got stuck at giving the path to my integrated nfc chip. I want to run the python script in termux (linux emulator). The goal would be to create something similar to these: [reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite) and this: [writer/emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nfcpy on Android phones, it only supports a selected set of [NFC chips](https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clf.html#device-drivers) which won't be in any Android phone

Comment: Oh okay thank you :(